# Call overloaded methods from Ironpython

Tags: overloading, ironpython

I would like to call the [`Curve.Trim(CurveEnd, Double)`](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/html/M_Rhino_Geometry_Curve_Trim.htm) method from the [RhinoCommon](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/) API via IronPython. How can I make sure I don't get the overload for [`Curve.Trim(Double, Double)`](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/html/M_Rhino_Geometry_Curve_Trim_2.htm)?

```py
crv.Trim(geo.CurveEnd.End, 8.8)
    #raised: Message: expected float, got CurveEnd
```

Note: If you want to try it yourself you will need to install a [trial version of Rhino](http://www.rhino3d.com/download/rhino/5.0/evaluationtimed). It includes a Python editor.

**Edit / Addition:**  the `.Overloads` property as mentioned by Jeff does not work here either. A snippet for testing:

```py
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino.Geometry as geo
import System

# first draw a curve longer than 8.8 units
crvO = rs.GetObject() # to pick that curve on the 3d GUI screen 
crv = rs.coercecurve(crvO)  # to get Rhino.Geometry.Curve

# these both don't work:
crv.Trim(geo.CurveEnd.End, 8.8) 
    #Message: expected float, got CurveEnd

crv.Trim.Overloads[geo.CurveEnd, System.Double](geo.CurveEnd.End, 8.8) 
    #Message: Trim() takes at least 2147483647 arguments (2 given)
```

[rhinscriptsyntax](https://github.com/mcneel/rhinopython/tree/master/scripts/rhinoscript) is a library based on Rhino namespace from [RhinoCommon](http://4.rhino3d.com/5/rhinocommon/)

Comment: Is `float` a `System.Double` in IronPython?

Comment: Yes, the literal `8.8` should be represented as a System.Double (tested on IronPython 2.7.3).

Comment: @Goswin, could you provide a full source snippet? With proper creation/assignment/.. of `crv` and `geo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `.Overloads` property to access a method's overloads:

```
csv.Trim.Overloads[CurveEnd, float](geo.CurveEnd.End, 8.8)
```

[The docs.](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#method-overloads)

Comment: unfortunatly this raised: "Message: Trim() takes at least 2147483647 arguments (2 given)"

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party. But this code works (out the override).

```
import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import Rhino
import scriptcontext as sc
import System

crv_id = rs.GetObject()
crv = rs.coercecurve(crv_id)
trimmed = crv.Trim(Rhino.Geometry.CurveEnd.End, 4)
sc.doc.Objects.Replace(crv_id, trimmed)
sc.doc.Views.Redraw()
```

Comment: yes, this now works for me too in Rhino5 SR14. Is this due to an update of Ironpython?